# What is the difference between open ball and neighborhood in real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm learning real analysis.

> Open ball: The collection of points $x \in X$ satisfying $|x - x_{0}| < r$ is called the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x_{0}$
>
> Neighborhood: A neighborhood of  $x_{0} \in X$ is an open ball of
>   radius r > 0 in $X$ that is centered at $x_{0}$

I'm using Real and Complex Analysis written by Christopher Apelian and Steve Surace.
In my mind, open ball = a collection of points satisfy certain requirement = neighborhood. I do not find out any differences between open ball and neighborhood. Could any one explain it? Thanks!

Comment: By those definitions *neighborhood of* $x$ and *open ball centred at* $x$ are indeed the same thing; that’s not the usual definition of *neighborhood*, however.

Answer (score 14):

Let's discuss the 1-dimensional case. An open ball in $\Bbb R$ is a set given by
$$
  B(x,r):=\{y\in \Bbb R:|y-x|<r\}.
$$
These sets are very important as they allow us to define the [topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology) on $\Bbb R$, i.e. it allows us to say which sets are open and which are not. Topology is one of the key structures to work with uncountable spaces, $\Bbb R$ in particular.

The neighborhood of a point $x\in \Bbb R$ is *any* subset $N_x\subseteq \Bbb R$  which contains some ball $B(x,r)$ around the point $x$. Note that in general one does not ask neighborhood to be open sets, but it depends on the author of a textbook you have in hands.

For example, if $x = 1$ then $(0.5,1.5)$ is a ball (of a radius $0.5$) around $x$, and $(0.5,1.5)\cup [2,4]$ is a neighborhood of $x$ which is not a ball (neither around $x$, nor around any other point).

As Brian has mentioned, indeed in your case these definitions are equivalent - but this is an unusual way to define neighborhoods.

Answer (score 2):

An open ball about x is a ball about a point $x$. A neighborhood of $x$ is commonly defined as an  set containing $x$ in its interior.

A neighborhood need not be  a ball/other trivial shape just a set containing $x$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott true. I originally had the neighborhoods defined as an open set. I'll update it.